# Sveltekit form submission request empty

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit app that displays a list of items. Each item has a 'delete' link, that triggers a JavaScript function. This function populates a hidden form element with the id of selected item to delete and submits the form, please see below.

```
let departmentIdToDelete: string | undefined = undefined

function confirmDelete(id: Number, title: String) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the ' + title + ' department')) {
        const form = document.querySelector('form') as HTMLFormElement
        departmentIdToDelete = id.toString()
        form.submit()
    }
}
```

And the simple form:

```
<form method="post" use:enhance>
    <input
        type="hidden"
        name="departmentIdToDelete"
        id="departmentIdToDelete"
        bind:value={departmentIdToDelete}
    />
</form>
```

When I submit the form, the default form action on the corresponding +page.server.ts receives the event but the request object is empty? The console log is below. Any suggestions as to why this may be the case? Many thanks.

```
event object = {"cookies":{},"locals":{"auth":{"auth":{"adapter":{},"sessionCookieOption":{"sameSite":"lax","path":"/"},"sessionExpiresIn":{"activePeriod":86400000,"idlePeriod":1209600000},"env":"DEV","hash":{},"autoDatabaseCleanup":true,"csrfProtection":true,"origin":[],"experimental":{"debugMode":false}},"context":{"request":{"url":"http://localhost:5173/departments","method":"POST","headers":{"origin":"http://localhost:5173","cookie":"auth_session=SOME_VALUE"}}},"validatePromise":null,"validateUserPromise":null,"storedSessionId":"SOME_OTHER_VALUE"}},"params":{},"request":{},"route":{"id":"/(admin)/departments"},"url":"http://localhost:5173/departments","isDataRequest":false,"isSubRequest":false}
```

Comment: `bind:` on a hidden field is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit:* I missed something important, updates to the document happen asynchronously, so a change to the variable `departmentIdToDelete` will not be reflected immediately. You can either [use `tick`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#tick) to wait for the update or do this differently using the [`enhance` submit function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance).

```js
// make it async
async function confirmDelete(id: Number, title: String) {
   // ...
   departmentIdToDelete = id.toString();
   await tick();
   form.submit()
}
```

Using `enhance`:

```js
function onSubmit({ formData }) {
  // Replaces hidden field entirely
  formData.set('departmentIdToDelete', departmentIdToDelete)
}
```

```html
<form method="post" use:enhance={onSubmit}>
```

Not sure if this can work with programmatic submission, you certainly should use `form.requestSubmit()` instead of just `submit()` as that circumvents things like events and validation.

---

The request object in all likelihood is not empty, it is just not JSON serializable.

You should be able to get values by using `formData`, along the lines of:

```js
export const actions = {
  default: async ({ request }) => {
    const data = await request.formData();
    const idToDelete = +data.get('departmentIdToDelete'); // `name` of field here
    // ...
  }
}
```

Also, you should not be using `document.querySelector`. Use something like [`bind:this`](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#bind-this) to store element references or use *relative* queries to not violate component boundaries (e.g. in an event handler use `e.target.querySelector` or `e.target.closest`).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried what you suggested above but no luck I'm afraid, console logging the idToDelete var is empty. So it seems like the request may indeed be empty :( Can you elaborate your comment "bind: on a hidden field is pointless" please? Many thanks

Comment: Use an *actual debugger* and inspect the objects, maybe you mistyped something like the name of the field somewhere. [`bind:` is for two-way bindings](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#bind-property), it is only necessary for getting values "out" of an input on user interaction, there will never be any user interaction with a hidden field.

Comment: @bennythemink: Just noticed an issue and updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you H.B., the tick() function worked! I will try the enhance once I clean up my code a little. Thanks for your help!